# Find number of repeating visitors in a month - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL and my data looks something like this:

```
UserID    TimeStamp
1          2014-02-03
2          2014-02-03
3          2014-02-03
1          2014-03-03
2          2014-03-03
6          2014-03-03
7          2014-03-03
```

This is just dummy data for 2 days in which some `UserID` is getting repeated on both the days. I would like to find out the number of repeated `UserId` every month. For this example the final result set should look like:

```
Count    Year    Month
0        2014    2
2        2014    3
```

In the above table, March 2014 has 2 repeated `UserID` and Feb 2014 has none.
I can find out the distinct `UserID` for each month but not the repeated `UserID`. Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

Comment: Repeated from the previous month only or the whole year or ever?

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    count(distinct userid) as "Count",
    extract(year from t0.timestamp) as "Year",
    extract(month from t0.timestamp) as "Month"
from
    t t1
    inner join
    t t0 using (userid)
where t0.timestamp < date_trunc('month', t1.timestamp)
group by 2, 3
```

or may be faster

```
select
    count(distinct userid) as "Count",
    extract(year from t0.timestamp) as "Year",
    extract(month from t0.timestamp) as "Month"
from t t1
where exists (
    select 1
    from t
    where
        userid = t1.userid
        and
        timestamp < date_trunc('month', t1.timestamp)
)
group by 2, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select yyyymm, sum(case when cnt > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as dupcnt
from (select to_char(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM') as yyyymm, userid, count(*) as cnt
      from table t
      group by to_char(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM'), userid
     ) t
group by yyyymm
order by yyyymm;
```

Comment: this query only gives me 0 and 1. I want the total number of repeating UserID in every month

Comment: @Patthebug . . . This query should return the total number of user ids that appear more than one time in each month, now that I've fixed the syntax error of the missing `userid` from the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

This might work, have not tested it out yet.

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT(UserId))
  , EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TIMESTAMP TimeStamp) AS Year
  , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIMESTAMP Timestamp) AS Month 
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY TimeStamp
```

Comment: this will give me number of unique UserID in a month, I want the number of repeating UserID in every month

Answer (score 0):

To rephrase your question:

How many users are not new (i.e. already visited the shop/website/whatever in a previous month) for each month?

```
SELECT
   yr, mon,
   COUNT(*) AS all_users,
   COUNT(*) - SUM(repeated) AS new_users,
   SUM(repeated) AS existing_users
FROM
 (
   SELECT UserId, 
      EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TimeStamp) AS yr,
      EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TimeStamp) AS mon,
      CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() -- 1st time users get 0
                OVER (PARTITION BY UserId
                      ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TimeStamp) ,
                               EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TimeStamp)) = 1 
           THEN 0 
           ELSE 1
      END AS repeated
   FROM vt
   GROUP BY UserId,
      EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TimeStamp),
      EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TimeStamp)
 ) AS dt
GROUP BY yr,mon
ORDER BY 1,2
```

The inner GROUP BY is needed if there are multiple rows for a user within the same month.