# Returning customers

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, subquery

Let' say I have a table `web.orders` with two columns:
`user_id` (integer)  unique identifier of the user
`created_at` (integer) timestamp in epoch

And I want to know how many returning customers are there in the last 7 days or the previous month.

So first of all I guess I have list all the unique user_id -s from the last 7 days, then search everyone of them in the earlier part of the table. And then summarise the hits.

I examined this two questions on the subject, but had no luck to convert them to work for me:
[Find number of repeating visitors in a month - PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666759/find-number-of-repeating-visitors-in-a-month-postgresql)
[PostgreSQL: Identifying return visitors based on date - joins or window functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446865/postgresql-identifying-return-visitors-based-on-date-joins-or-window-function)

Please anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `exists`:

```
select count(distinct o.user_id) no_returning_visitors
from web.orders o
where 
    created_at >= extract(epoch from date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '7' day)
    and created_at < extract(epoch from date_trunc('month', current_date))
    and exists (
        select 1 
        from web.orders o1
        where 
            o1.user_id = o.user_id 
            and o1created_at < extract(epoch from date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '7' day)
    )
```

Comment: Thank you! I helps a lot! I'm studying it but can not understand why is this row necessary:  

`and created_at < extract(epoch from date_trunc('month', current_date))`   

There is a typo in your solution: `o1created_at`

Comment: And probably we should use `day` instead of `month` in the first and third conditions, right?